# Nginx ingress controller doesn't keep url over redirect

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, nginx-reverse-proxy, kubernetes-ingress

I am trying to setup a nginx ingress controller; here is the yaml of the ingress:

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-rules
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/force-ssl-redirect: "false"

spec:
  rules:
  - host: 
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /discover-service
        backend:
          serviceName: discover-service
          servicePort: discover-port
```

When I hit http://IP/discover-service it shows an HTML without CSS and JS. As I can see, they are looked under http://IP/eureka/css/file.css instead of http://IP/discover-service/css/file.css.

How can I preserve the original url in this case?

**UPDATE #1**

Now I can serve the static files by creating two ingresses like:

```
ingress-rules-discover-root.yaml

[..]
metadata:
  name: ingress-rules-discover-root

  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
    [...]

spec:
  rules:
  - host: 
    http:
      paths:

      - path: /discover-service
        backend:
          serviceName: discover-service
          servicePort: discover-port
```

and another one

```
[...]
metadata:
  name: ingress-rules-discover-path
  namespace: default
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
    [...]

spec:
  rules:
  - host: 
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /eureka
        backend:
          serviceName: discover-service
          servicePort: discover-port
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe in this case you need to remove the annotation:

```
nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
```

This annotation makes the ingress rewrite `http://IP/discover-service/css/file.css` to `http://IP/eureka/css/file.css`

Comment: if I remove that annotation, I get 404 from the service (Spring boot application in this case) at  http://IP/discover-service instead of a plain html.

Comment: So it's not clear on the question are your static files served under `http://IP/eureka/css`?

Comment: I update the question. Now basically it is working but I don't know if I can achieve the same thing in another way. This seems to be too confused. Should I create many ingresses for every case like above that I have?

Comment: Yes, that should work. One that rewrites and another that doesn't